# What are the testosterone tests that I can take to prove that my low libido is really a testosterone problem?

Tags: endocrinology, sex, testosterone, test, libido

I understand that ( correct me if I am wrong) the Sex Hormone Binding Globulin ( SHBG) test is [one of the tests that can be used to evaluate one's libido](https://labtestsonline.org/understanding/analytes/shbg/tab/test/).

> The sex hormone binding globulin (SHBG) test may be used to help
>   evaluate men for low testosterone and women for excess testosterone
>   production. It may be ordered in conjunction with other tests to
>   evaluate the status of a person's sex hormones.

Besides this SHBG, what other testosterone tests I should take if I think that they can be responsible for my low libido level? My goal is to

1. Identify those testosterone
2. Try to increase them
3. So that I can get my libido back!

Comment: there are more than one types of testosterone?